# How can a command line program support piping arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line, pipe

I have written a c++ command line program that successfully reads certain lines from a file, and then does something with the this data.

But, I want to use pipes in unix and windows to accomplish the same task. In order words:

`cat file | ./myProgram`

I have tried to google this, but I didn't find anything useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just read from `cin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system handles pipes.  In the example you posted, the contents of `file` are sent to the standard input (`cin`) of `myProgram`.

So to be "pipe compatible" your program will need to read from `cin` to get its input.

Comment: yes, and be careful when handling under windows system, a similar issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420233/ffmpeg-av-interleaved-write-frame-broken-pipe-under-windows